# Selenium tab crashed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error when trying to access any data (find_elements)

What I already tried:

```
 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

And a few more options like disable GPU, Javascript, etc.
I don’t know, maybe the site itself is to blame, because on others there was almost never such a problem

Chromedriver 102.0.5005.61

Chrome 102.0.5005.63

Windows 11

I cleaned up my code from everything superfluous and this is where the error occurs

```
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

for u in [x.strip() for x in [
    "https://www.planetminecraft.com/texture-packs/?time_machine=y-2022&order=order_views&op1=128"]]:  # open("links.txt").readlines()
    capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
    d = uc.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)
    page = 1
    while True:
        d.get(u)
        while d.execute_script("return document.readyState") != "interactive":
            print(d.execute_script("return document.readyState"))
        links = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in d.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="r-title"]')]
        print(links)
```

Error:

```
          File "C:\Users\Mostalk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 155, in get_attribute
    attribute_value = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\Mostalk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 879, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\Mostalk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Mostalk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0100D953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F9F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8C580+836992]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E363+779107]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E04F+778319]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7C565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CB68+772968]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CAF8+772856]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E82D5A+798042]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7DD3B+777531]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E265+778853]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E04F+778319]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7C565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CB68+772968]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CAF8+772856]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E82D5A+798042]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7DD3B+777531]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E265+778853]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7E04F+778319]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7D646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7C565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7CB68+772968]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E94AF2+871154]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8EBBB+846779]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8E735+845621]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8EF2F+847663]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8F8EA+850154]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EE5249+1200713]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ED449C+1131676]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EE4812+1198098]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ED42B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAE860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAF756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0127CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0126F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0109EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0109D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FA5F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FAA898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FAA985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FB3AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76DC6739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77C48E7F+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77C48E4D+1165]
```

Comment: Not sure of the cause of the ex, but suspect multiple timeouts.  Keep the pageloadstrategy at default (don't set it at all) and remove your readystate checks.  (those will not be helpful as it's not clear when that script will run and this state can be in flux...)  With pageloadstrategy at default the .get() will wait for a full page load.  You will see stale element exceptions if JS is making changes to the DOM after the fact. (when you use getAttribute() method) That's why they are thrown... so that you can deal with the situation when those exceptions are caught.

Comment: @pcalkins, thanks for answer. But now i get other error.

Comment: @pcalkins. from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed

Comment: That can be caused by a command timeout...  (timeout period from driver to browser or driver to grid)... Selenium will delete the session if that happens.  If you are using version 4 of Selenium be sure to update it to the latest version.

Comment: I have latest version 4.1.5 from pip.

Comment: @pcalkins, Now it's run a few times. Miscellaneous errors, now gave "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10" (I set d.set_page_load_timeout(10). What is the best way to avoid these errors? So that the session is not deleted

Comment: @pcalkins, I discovered one thing. It seems that selenium is in conflict with running normal chrome, from which I am currently writing, if I close it, then everything works

Comment: That's interesting...  there can be a lot of different causes for the error you are seeing, but the command timeout is different than page load timeout.  I don't think it can be set... (except when creating a hub/grid) I was experiencing some of these things but the more recent versions of Selenium and Chromedriver seemed to solve it.  Never really nailed it down, though.   No clue as to why a manual session of chrome would cause this.  I can say that more recent versions of Chromedriver do not play well with driver.close() method so avoid using that when tearing down.